# EXC_BAD_ACCESS "attempted to retain deallocated object" in `deinit`

Tags: ios, swift

The following code-snippet fails in `deinit` with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and previously with an EXC_BREAKPOINT in method `_swift_abortRetainUnowned` with a message "**attempted to retain deallocated object**".

I'm wondering *why* the imported `self` will be retained when it is captured as `unowned` - and even though the closure is declared explicitly as `@noescape`. IMHO, self shouldn't be retained here when imported into the closure.

In contrast, when `self` will be captured as a *strong* reference, the code succeeds. I would understand it if it were the other way around. What I'm missing?

```
import Foundation

public class Bar {

    private let _id = 1

    func foo(@noescape f: ()->()) -> () {
        f()
    }

    deinit {
        foo() { [unowned self] in
            let id = self._id
        }
    }    
}



func test() ->() {
    var cr = Bar()
}        
test()
```

Stack:

```
UnownedSelf`_swift_abortRetainUnowned:
    0x100174d90 <+0>:  leaq   0x1979d(%rip), %rax       ; "attempted to retain deallocated object"
    0x100174d97 <+7>:  movq   %rax, 0x65ff2(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
    0x100174d9e <+14>: int3   
->  0x100174d9f <+15>: nop
```

Comment: Since it's coming back nil already, self might be getting deallocated before your completion. You can try [weak self] instead.

Comment: Any more explanation on this?

Comment: @Rpranata Do you need more explanation _what_ I'm asking, or do you need more info _why_ it's crashing?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Sorry. I meant, more explanation on why its crashing? In my case, it is also crashing when declared and I am pretty sure that `self` is there when it crash (there is a strong circular reference that makes sure `self` is not deallocated)